# Use of AMEX, MasterCard, Visa without the word "card"

Tags: contractions, possessive-pronouns

Do you say my AMEX, my Visa Gold, my MasterCard to mean your credit cards issued by a relevant company?

> I always take (my) Visa Gold, when I go abroad on holiday.
>
> Will you accept AMEX (at a gas station).

Comment: I certainly don't say *"I always take my MasterCard card,"* although search reveals that some people do.

Comment: I generally omit *card* when speaking of my credit cards. At all restaurants, I kindly ask the server to *charge it [the food] to my Master*.

Comment: @JakeRegier Good one that. I must try it - "Charge it to my master, my good man!"

Comment: And the master would usually mean the trouble-and-strife, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1):

A more general term you can use for all credit cards is to ask "Do you take **plastic**?"

Answer (score 0):

I have heard it used as simply Visa or Mastercard when refering to the credit cards.

A merchant can and has said to me on numerous occasions:

> We accept cash, check, and Visa.